# Push/Pull Value(s) to Array in ArangoJS

Tags: arangodb, arangojs

I'm transitioning to ArangoDB for its power as a graph database and am struggling with the simple stuff.

If I have a document...

```
{ _id:'1234', tags:['apple','orange'] }
```

how can I update it to push or pull a value from the array? I would expect the syntax to be something like this, but didn't find anything in the docs...

```
collection.update({ _id:'1234' },{ tags:pull('mango') })
collection.update({ _id:'1234' },{ tags:push('avocado') })
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You achieve this with AQL. For example

```
FOR c in collection UPDATE c WITH { tags : PUSH(c.tags, 'avocado')} IN collection
```

https://docs.arangodb.com/3.11/aql/high-level-operations/update/